# Free Dataset Resources?

Tags: dataset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Locating freely available data samples](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7/locating-freely-available-data-samples)

Where can I find freely accessible data sources?

I'm thinking of sites like

- http://www2.census.gov/census_2000/datasets/?

Comment: Actually, I think the previous question is more a subset of this one. EAMann was asking for a datasets with some particular characteristics (although I'm not sure anybody is paying attention to those criteria); this question is wide-open.  For example, I feel comfortable voting up many of these answers, because they are, in fact, datasets, but not any of the answers on the previous question, because I haven't opened them up to see if they suit EAMann's requests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Amazon has free Public Data sets for use with EC2.

http://aws.amazon.com/publicdatasets/

Here's a list: http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/kbcategory.jspa?categoryID=243

Answer (score 5):

I really like the [FRED](http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/), from the St. Louis Fed (economics data). You can chart the series or more than one series, you can do some transformations to your data and chart it, and the NBER recessions are shaded.

Answer (score 4):

For time series data, try the [Time Series Data Library](http://robjhyndman.com/TSDL).

Answer (score 3):

http://infochimps.org/ - is a good resource for free data sets.

Comment: Maybe I'm not looking in the right place, but for me in February 2019, this website has no data sets, much less free ones

Answer (score 3):

For governmental data:

US: http://www.data.gov/

World: http://www.guardian.co.uk/world-government-data