# Publications in the social sciences or psychology based on freely available datasets?

Tags: dataset, psychometrics, psychology, reproducible-research, social-science

There are a lot of datasets freely available across the web (see CV questions [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145/free-dataset-resources),  [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7/locating-freely-available-data-samples), or [here](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/4354/which-r-packages-have-good-collections-of-psychology-datasets)). Yet, I want the reverse: I am looking for **a list of publications** in the social sciences or psychology that are **based on freely available datasets**. My goal is to use them in stats classes and have student redo the analysis themselves. I think its a particularly nice learning effect to see that the things we do in class are the same things that are done in the real world.

So my question: Do you know publications in this field using freely available data sources?
The statistical method is secondary. All methods are welcome.

Comment: Below we have one post for Economics. Still my wish would be to have something similar for Psychology and Sociology.

Answer (score 4):

I have been doing the same thing. In the end I started with datasets I knew to be publicly available, and looked at the websites of these datasets. Often it contains a list of publications that used that dataset.

You could also look [here](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de).

Comment: Thanks for the link :) Yet, do I see it correctly that this page is purely Economics?

Comment: As I understand them, they don't want to be, but the persons taking the initiative were economists, so that influences the results...

Comment: (+1) I have upvoted this answer because--exceptionally for such list-of-list threads--it describes a *method* to obtain the desired collection.