# Free data set for very high dimensional classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, dataset, large-data

What are the **freely available data set for classification with more than 1000 features** (or sample points if it contains curves)?

There is already a community wiki about free data sets:
[Locating freely available data samples](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7/locating-freely-available-data-samples/)

But here, it would be nice to have a **more focused list that can be used more conveniently**, also I propose the following rules:

1. One post **per dataset**
2. **No** link to set of dataset
3. each data set **must** be associated with

   - a **name** (to figure out what it is about)  and a link to the dataset (R datasets can be named with package name)
   - the number of features (let say it is **p**) the size of the dataset (let say it is **n**) and the number of labels/class (let say it is **k**)
   - a typical **error rate** from your experience (state the used algorithm in to words) or from the litterature (in this last case link the paper)

Comment: +1, but the ones from NIPS2003 have train.labels only -- the NIPS2003 paper says clearly "validation and test set labels are withheld".

Comment: Thanks. The comment about NIPS is for the answer from @mbq .

Comment: Anyone here have a high dimensional dataset with more than two class labels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Dorothea**](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Dorothea)
n=1950
p=100000 (0.1M, half is artificially added noise)
k=2 (~10x unbalanced)
From [NIPS2003](http://www.nipsfsc.ecs.soton.ac.uk/papers/NIPS2003-Datasets.pdf).

Comment: Can you explain how this is 100000 features? I look at the training data and each line has maybe 2500 integers per line.

Comment: It is a sparse array, integer N means attribute N value is 1.

Answer (score 3):

[**Arcene**](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Arcene)
n=900
p=10000 (3k is artificially added noise)
k=2 (~balanced)
From [NIPS2003](http://www.nipsfsc.ecs.soton.ac.uk/papers/NIPS2003-Datasets.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

[**Dexter**](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Dexter)
n=2600
p=20000 (10k+53 is artificial noise)
k=2 (balanced)
From [NIPS2003](http://www.nipsfsc.ecs.soton.ac.uk/papers/NIPS2003-Datasets.pdf).

Comment: I don't understand... one set per person?

Comment: @robin & @mbq I would suggest keeping it one dataset per post. This so people can indicate with votes which of the suggested ones there also suggest/support

Comment: @Peter, OK, I follow your idea, I have changed the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

[**Gisette**](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Gisette)
n=13500
p=5000 (half is artificially added noise)
k=2 (balanced)
From [NIPS2003](http://www.nipsfsc.ecs.soton.ac.uk/papers/NIPS2003-Datasets.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

**Prostate** (gene expression array)

- k=2
- n=48+52
- p=6033

Available via (among other) R package [spls](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spls/) 
name of the dataset: prostate

error rate =  3/102 (see [here](http://www.stat.wisc.edu/%7Ekeles/Papers/C_SPLS.pdf)) also I think there are paper which show 1/102 error rate. I would say this is an easy test case.