# Where can I find good publicly available data that I could use to teach z-scores to my college students?

Tags: dataset

I am sick of using the examples in the book. Is there an easy place to find data for which z-score/percentile/normal distribution stuff would be easy to see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may wish to read answers to this existing question on [freely available datasets](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7/locating-freely-available-data-samples).

In general, I imagine that you'd want a dataset with some interesting metric variables.
In psychology research methods classes that I've taught, we've often looked at datasets with intelligence or personality test scores.

If you want a personality example, I have some [personality data and metadata on github](https://github.com/jeromyanglim/Sweave_Personality_Reports) based on the [IPIP](http://ipip.ori.org/), an public domain measure of the Big 5 factors of personality.

- [github repository home](https://github.com/jeromyanglim/Sweave_Personality_Reports)
- [data](https://github.com/jeromyanglim/Sweave_Personality_Reports/blob/master/data/ipip.tsv)
- [metadata](https://github.com/jeromyanglim/Sweave_Personality_Reports/blob/master/meta/ipipmeta.tsv)
- [David Smith's summary](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2010/12/how-to-create-pdf-reports-with-r.html)

Answer (score 2):

One good website where you can find data for different disciplines.

[Rob Hyndman's Time Series Data library](http://robjhyndman.com/TSDL/)

Answer (score 0):

the following repositories hold a variety of datasets:

[Statlib](http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/)

[UCI machine Learning Repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/)

[KDNuggets Link List](http://www.kdnuggets.com/datasets/)

and, as said before, many more at:
[this question.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7/locating-freely-available-data-samples)