# Free database of historical events in database format?

Tags: dataset

Is there a free database of historical events that's in database 
format (ie, CSV or some other easily imported format)?

I realize Wikipedia has extensive historical information, but it's not 
in database format.

I also visited historymole.com, but the information they have is both 
incomplete and provides very limited free access.

I want to create a historical database, but wondered if one already existed.

Comment: I can't quite tell what you're asking for. Eg, a csv file is not a database. You may be interested in checking out [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7/locating-freely-available-data-samples), or just searching the site under the [tag:dataset] tag.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is off-topic here. You can see [here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/1298/2970) and [here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/1032/2970) for more. Someone may still provide a helpful hint.

Comment: I am trying to set something like this up, mainly for the purpose of making visualisations of data on international development and particularly economic and education policy. The beta version is here: http://devtimelines.appspot.com. You may have in mind longer term historical events (this only goes back to the 1970s) in which case this will be less useful for you. It doesn't yet allow the data to be accessed externally but I intend to add this facility (especially if there is actually a demand for it!)

Comment: Thanks, Stuart! I'm trying to do something similar (but not identical) to chronozoomproject.org, so I'm looking for events from the beginning of time to the end.

Comment: I've now created a very minimal such db. Sample query: http://b8513f7348b65bfbc5134287f85780bf.history.db.barrycarter.info/