# How to create artificial data with one binary response variable?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining

I want to check various classification model like random forest, tree, knn,etc. I used some bench marking data set but now I need to simulate my own data set with a binary response variable.

Comment: No, since your question is unclear. If you want to simulate a certain data generation model you can do so, but it unclear what exactly your question and your problem is.

Comment: Welcome to the site. 

If you are asking about how to program this, then the question should go on StackOverflow. If you are asking about statistical properties, it should stay here. Please clarify.

Comment: I guess the question is the following: "How can one simulate data with binary response and features with predictive power", i.e. an artificial dataset for a binary classification problem. @ZKHAN can you clarify ?

Comment: We *can* help you, @ZKHAN, but we need to know a lot more about your situation & your goals. There are *lots* of ways to simulate data, eg, do you want to simulate data from a decision tree w/ certain properties so that you can check how well a k-nearest-neighbor algorithm can mimic the CART, something else? You may find the following blog post helpful: [how to ask a statistics question](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/).

Comment: Yes, I need an artificial data set produced through any model. The response should be binary and predictive features can belong to any distribution, e.g. normal, uniform. And I want to check the performance of knn and some other classifiers using those artificial data.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the  R-package `mlbench`. Among various reallife datasets it contains generators for artificial ones, e.g.

```
mlbench.ringnorm(n=1000)
```

Another options is Data Mining Framework Rapidminer (java), which contains some more dataset generator for real-world-problems like Churning. For an overview, see [this page (from the API)](http://rapid-i.com/api/rapidminer-5.1/com/rapidminer/operator/io/AbstractExampleSource.html) and search for "Generator".

Note that artificial datasets **cannot** be used to show that a classification algorithm is performing well. You may *only* explore certain properties of the algorithm or verify that a reproduction of another one's implementation is correct.

So if you want to perform a solid comparison, use real world datasets. You may find some here: [Locating freely available data samples](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7/locating-freely-available-data-samples)