# time series regression and correlated residuals

Tags: regression, time-series, self-study

Can somebody please introduce me a time series regression **dataset** that has many variables and data point?

In a nutshell, I have a model of the form of

$$y_t=X'\beta+v_t$$

where $v_t=\sum_i^p \phi_iv_{t-i}+e_t$ and $e_t\sim^{iid} N(0,\sigma^2<\infty)$. Note that I can artificially simulate a dataset. Then I need a real dataset. For sure there are many datasets that this model works well on them but I cannot find anything at the mean time.I  also have checked this page [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7/locating-freely-available-data-samples) but no progress. I would be thankful if somebody introduce me a dataset and probably associate paper.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the FRED-MD monthly database from the St. Louis Fed [here](https://research.stlouisfed.org/econ/mccracken/fred-databases/). An accompanying paper, FRED-MD: A Monthly Database for Macroeconomic Research, can be found [here](https://research.stlouisfed.org/wp/2015/2015-012.pdf).

Some journal articles in economics such as Econometrica and the Journal of Applied Econometrics provide both data and replication files so perhaps you could find some more large data sets there.